# Excel for Mac: Convert Windows split to txt macro

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel

I'm a total VB hack - as in cut/copy/paste and try to make things work. The code below worked on my Windows machine, but won't work on my Mac.

I get a file/path access error on this line:

```
Open MYFILE & "C2NXT_STD.txt" For Output As #FileNum
```

I'm sure it is due to the `Open MYFILE` portion referencing the folder path. Maybe I really have a permissions error?

```
Public Sub a_SaveAsTextWithDelimiter()
Const MYFILE = "Macintosh HD/Users/darrenmason/Documents/Products/Creator NXT/Serials/"
Dim Last_Column As Integer
Dim Last_Row As Long
Dim FileNum As Integer
Dim My_Range As Range
Dim My_Cell As Variant

FileNum = FreeFile

With ActiveSheet.Cells
    Last_Column = .Find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
    Last_Row = .Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
End With

Set My_Range = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & Last_Row)

Open MYFILE & "C2NXT_STD.txt" For Output As #FileNum
For Each My_Cell In My_Range
    If My_Cell.Row Mod 1000 = 0 Then
        Close #FileNum
        Open MYFILE & "C2NXT_STD_" & (My_Cell.Row \ 1000) & "_" & (Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")) & ".txt" For Output As #FileNum
    End If
    Print #FileNum, My_Cell.Value
Next
Close #FileNum
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the "Macintosh HD" from your path, so that it starts with the slash.

i.e. `Const MYFILE = "/Users/darrenmason/Documents/Products/Creator NXT/Serials/"`

Comment: Thank Randolph, tried that but same error. Have also tried replacing slashes with : to no avail.

Comment: I actually received a brand new script from another forum and am having the exact same error with the folder path. So I'm down to a formatting issue or permissions issue. Anything special I should be doing with the spaces in the folder path?